# How to get TimeStamping Token and apply it to PDF file?

Tags: java, timestamp, trusted-timestamp, pdfstamper, rfc3161

I'm trying to get a Time Stamping token from a server, and apply this token to a PDF file that will be signed later.
I'm asking if someone has already works with a similar concept using java 
I have some information about the TimeStamping Authority (TSA) such as:

- Policy    : 1.2.504.1.1.1.1.1.3.1.1
- Format : RFC 3161
- Algorithm : SHA1 associated with RSA with 2048 bits.
- UTC timezone

How to get the certified date and put it in the PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

your question can be decoupled in two sub-questions:

1. how to generate a signature according to a Time-stamp protocol (TSP) describe in [RFC 3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt)
2. how to integrate the signature to a PDF file?

**Sub-question 1:**
To solve the first question, you need two stakeholders: a TSP client and a TSP server. A client must sent a request to a server (like every client-server communication) and the server send back a response to the client. Like you already mentioned a TSA (Time Stamping Authority) has the responsibility to handle the request. The challenge is to be able to send a request to TSA server. I call it challenge because the construction of the request according to TSP is complex. Each client request must be formatted as TimeStampReq (see [RFC 3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) section 2.4.1) and TSP extends also a standard called Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS), which is describe in [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652). To help you at this stage you can use one cryptographical library such as BouncyCastle or Eldos, which implement CMS and/or TSP specifications in Java and/or C#.

The BouncyCastle is my favorite i have already use it. It will make the following task for you out of the box:

1. Hash the PDF/document you want to sign with a hash algorithm you have choose (make sure that this algorithm is always secured or recommended)
2. Create an TimeStampReq for you by using the parameters you have passed

**Sub-question 2:**
this step is not necessary to assure the integrity of the document or the Time-Stamp itself. You can store a created Time-Stamp and signed PDF/Document separately. I'm not a PDF expert. But i know that it's possible to embedded a digital signature into it. I'm not able to tell you which format of digital signature(s) is/are supported by which version of PDF and how to integrate it into a PDF.